# Rails HABTM ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have set an association using HABTM with Rails, with two models: Site and User.

**Site.rb**

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :fae_users,
    class_name: "Site",
    foreign_key: "site_id",
    join_table: "sites_users",
    association_foreign_key: "fae_user_id"
```

**User.rb**

```
    has_and_belongs_to_many :sites,
      class_name: "User",
      foreign_key: "fae_user_id",
      join_table: "sites_users",
      association_foreign_key: "site_id"
```

**Schema.rb**

```
  create_table "sites_users", id: false, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "site_id"
    t.bigint "fae_user_id"
    t.index ["fae_user_id"], name: "index_sites_users_on_fae_user_id"
    t.index ["site_id"], name: "index_sites_users_on_site_id"
  end
```

**View: sites/_form.html.slim**

```
= f.collection_select :fae_user_ids, Fae::User.all, :id, :email, {}, {:multiple => true}
```

Now when I'm trying to update a Site, associating some User to it, I got the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Admin::SitesController#update
Couldn't find all Sites with 'id': (3, 2) (found 1 results, but was looking for 2). Couldn't find Site with id 2.
```

This is strange, because I don't understand when does Rails is looking for those Site ids, which are actually supposed to be User ids.
Site id appears to be correct in the params:

**Params of the request**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
 "site"=>
  {"site_status_id"=>"4",
   "fae_user_ids"=>["", "3", "2"],
   "prod_url"=>"",
   "demo_url"=>"",
   "template"=>"",
   "name"=>"Somesite",
   "site_option_ids"=>[""],
   "description"=>"",
   "domain"=>"",
   "discount"=>""},
 "id"=>"10"}
```

Something is going wrong, obviously !
Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Go to your rails console and type in Site.all - what is the result you are getting back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `class_name` keys backwards.

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :fae_users,
  class_name: 'Fae::User'

has_and_belongs_to_many :sites
```

You don't need to have the `class_name` attribute on the `User` model as Rails can infer the `Site` class.

Rails has very [extensive documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) for relations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

If I use your code, I now got the following error on the view:

`NameError in Admin::Sites#edit uninitialized constant Site::User`

`= f.collection_select :fae_user_ids, Fae::User.all, :id, :email, {}, {:multiple => true}`

Comment: I got it fixed now, thank you!
The class name was `Fae::User` because it came from an engine

Comment: @SimonMo Glad I could help! I was on the fence with `Fae::User` vs `User` from the code given.  I updated the answer for posterity. If you could accept the answer it will help future users if they have the same problem.